# linux-wide semaphore with a Java API

Tags: java, linux, semaphore

I need to prevent a certain application function from being run concurrently with itself.  The risk is significant because this function is in code submitted to java.util.Timer (to repeat every minute for several hours) and the process that sets up the function completes and goes back to the bash command line.  The user might then invoke the same program.  Another risk is from the user that has two or more console windows and they mistakenly run the program in both console windows.

I think an operating system-wide semaphore with a Java API might do the trick.  Is there such a Java archive available?

I was asked if multiple JVMs are used.  I think if multiple consoles are opened then multiple JVMs are implied.

This is my wrapper to use Java's Timer and TimerTask.

```
public final class TimedExecutorWrapper
{       ... various private members ... 
        public Timer go()
        {
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this.myTask, 
                                        this.startTodayAtThisTime, 
                                        this.frequencyInSeconds * 1000);
            TimerTask myTaskToInvokeCancel = new TaskToInvokeCancel(myTimer);

            // use the same Timer to schedule the task that cancels and purges
            myTimer.schedule(myTaskToInvokeCancel,
                             this.stopTodayAtThisTime);
            return myTimer;
        }

        private final class TaskToInvokeCancel extends TimerTask
        {
                private Timer timer; // to be cancelled and purged

                TaskToInvokeCancel(Timer timer)
                {
                    this.timer = timer;
                }

                public void run()
                {
                  this.timer.cancel(); // discards any scheduled tasks without 
                                     //  interfering with any running task
                  this.timer.purge(); 
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this a single JVM or multiple?

Comment: I don't know enough to answer this.  It is a command line utility written in Java.

Comment: Is the code that is exectued by java.util.Timer running in a single JVM signalled by the command line utility or in each of the command line utilities (apparently running in the background)?

Comment: I think I know what you're getting at.  Multiple console windows implies multiple JVMs and so multiple singletons.  Therefore the singleton pattern will not be suitable.

Comment: the two scenarios have very different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a 0 byte file 'methodname.LOCK' in a shared directory when you begin the operation, and delete it when you are done.  Creating it with a no recreate flag in Java should solve your problem.

Make sure to delete it in a 'finally' block so you are never left in a state where the file exists and continues to block the process from *ever* running

Comment: +1 for lock files. You can use [`File.createTempFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to create a temporary file. And calling [`deleteOnExit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()) on it will make sure it gets deleted when you app finishes.

Comment: This is a very good answer for the command line utility case.  I also have a Swing program that calls my various "command line" utilities. I like how Java has multiple `main()` programs.  In the Swing case, the life of the JVM will be longer so I cannot use the `deleteOnExit()` which is tied to the life of the JVM.  I decided to use `createNewFile` and manage deletion myself.

Comment: I don't think much of a lock file.  I expect you would have a problem if the different JVMs create the lock file at the same time?

Comment: There is a FileLock object that seems like it could be used in combination with the lock file idea.

Answer (score 1):

just open a serversocket at a specific port. if this succeeds there is no other application, if not an exception is thrown.

Comment: It works, but there is a small chance that this will interfere with some other application that needs to *use* that port.  Also, you are using system resources by keeping that socket open.

Answer (score 0):

The only standard Java feature I've seen that prohibits multiple instances of the same program is the `SingleInstanceService` in Java WebStart.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#SingleInstanceService

It requires you to create a JNLP file for your application, which is a bit cumbersome but may be very useful to you anyway.  Note that Java does not allow command line parameters to be passed to your program which may be very inconvenient in this situation.  Depends on what your command line says.

If Java WebStart does not work for you, then you must ask the operating system for a resource which is denied for subsequent requests and have it automatically released.  The only one of these not platform specific is the TCP/IP socket but these are rare and may be used by another program.  Under Linux you may ask for shared memory but I do not have personal experience with this.